# How to get a column with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I have written SQL query which brings data from multiple tables and displays the same in this format.[image].

I want the Sum of Total for every person and display in a new column, like the below.

Can you point some examples doing same kind of stuff please..

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports windowed aggregates you can add

```
,SUM(Total) OVER (PARTITION BY Name/*Or PersonId if not unique*/) AS All_Total
```

to your `SELECT` list

Comment: Thanks Martin. Very efficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

look for "sum" and "group by". But note, that grouping by name will invalidate the startDate and endDate.

edit: ah, mssql - nvm ;)